# HomeKit - HomeManagerDidUpdateHomes not called

Tags: ios, swift, homekit, ios-homekit

I'm trying to access the list of Homes provided by HomeKit on my network. However, `HomeManagerDidUpdateHomes` is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding HomeKit capability to the desired target